How can I define prop types for a React Native screen that will appear in two separate stacks?
I have a screen that I need to use in two separate stacks. I'm using the react-navigation library and the stacks themselves are nested in a Tab navigator that is the root of the app. I have the following Params lists for the two stacks;
export type RootTabsNavigatorParamsList = {
  screen_1: undefined
  screen_2: undefined
  screen_3: {func: () => Screen3Object| undefined}
}

export type StackNavigatorParamsList = {
    screen_2: undefined;
    screen_3: {func: () => Screen3Object| undefined};
}

I then use the following interface for screen_3;
interface Screen3Props extends NativeStackScreenProps<RootTabsNavigatorParamsList , "screen_3"> { }

How would I type the props for screen 3 to be able to use the props for both stacks? I'm using tsx so I need to type the NativeStackScreenProps with the params list of the respective stack navigators.
edit: Just tried to "or" the types and it seems to have worked, though I do not know if this is good practice;
interface Screen3Props extends NativeStackScreenProps<StackNavigatorParamsList | RootTabsNavigatorParamsList, "screen_3"> {};

